# Add string values into Java | Android Studio

Tags: java, android, string, android-studio

I have a string values . How can ı add to **text.setText("there")** on  JAVA Class.

**Strings**

```
    <resources>
        <string name="app_name">ViaDo</string>
        <string name="dkdinlenme">minute rest</string>
        <string name="baslat">Start</string>
        <string name="or">or</string>
        <string name="odevhatirlat">Remind Homework</string>
        <string name="dkcalisma">minute study</string>
        <string name="calisma">STUDY</string>
        <string name="hatirlatici">Create a reminder</string>
    </resources>
```

**JAVA Class**

```
 public class pomodoroscreen extends AppCompatActivity implements TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener {
    TextView dkclsm, yd, txtsaat, tur,dnlm;
    @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)   {
                 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                 setContentView(R.layout.activity_pomodoroscreen);
    dkclsm = findViewById(R.id.textView2);
                yd = findViewById(R.id.textView4);
    dnlm = findViewById(R.id.textView3);
                txtsaat = findViewById(R.id.txtsaat);
    
                 txtsaat.setText("I want add string there How can ı do this");
```

Comment: Please do **neither** alter the question after a valid answer has been offered **nor** vandalize it. If you have a new issue you are always welcome to open a new question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by:

```
getString(R.string.baslat);
```

Example:

```
txtsaat.setText(getString(R.string.baslat));
```

If the above one gives you an error here is Method 2:

```
this.getResources().getString(R.string.baslat);
```

where 'this' is your Activity Context.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a string from strings.xml to java class in this way.

In Java class

```
txtsaat.setText(getString(R.string.app_name));
```

If in case getString() shows an error try this way by calling context.

```
txtsaat.setText(getApplicationContext().getString(R.string.app_name));
```

In Kotlin

```
applicationContext.getString(R.string.app_name)
```